# PHP and MySQL many-to-many question

Tags: php, sql

Still wrapping my head around SQL and PHP, but hope someone can help with this:

I have the following tables:

1.

```
user table
- id
- name
- email
```

2.

```
user_group table
- user_id
- group_id
```

3.

```
group table
- id
- group_name
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between the user table and the group table. Now what I am trying to do build a browse users page which lists all the users in the system along with the groups that they belong to, so the page would look something like this:

```
Name: John Doe
Groups: football, tennis, swimming

Name: Jane Doe
Groups: hockey, basketball

Name: Jim Doe
Groups: hockey, football, rugby
```

etc. etc.

To accomplish this, I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT `user`.name, `group`.name 
FROM `user`, `user_group`, `group` 
WHERE `user`.id = `user_group`.user_id 
  AND `group`.id = `user_group`.group_id 
GROUP BY `user`.id, `group`.id
```

which returns results as follows:

```
1. John Doe | football
2. John Doe | tennis
3. John Doe | swimming
4. Jane Doe | hockey
5. Jane Doe | basketball
etc. etc.
```

As you can see, the results returned need to be manipulated in order to produce the comma separated groups shown earlier, as .

Is there a simple way to get the page to display the groups so that they are in a comma separated list for each user in MySQL?  Or do I have to write PHP code to loop through the results looking for duplicate IDs and generating the comma-separated lists of groups on the page? Or am I doing something completely wrong in my approach?

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it in one query atm, but I would fetch a list of all the users first, then loop through that list SELECTing the group.name WHERE user.name = $username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options (in order of my personal preference).

1. Don't group by user id, and iterate trough your result and create an multi dimensional array using the user id as a key.
2. Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), which isn't pretty.
3. Use separate queries for selecting all groups + users, and iterate to create an multi dimensional array.

Comment: It can have unforeseen issues with exceeding it's maximum length, and you don't receive the grouped information together when you need more then just the name, and requires you to map them yourself anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck. MySQL has a very handy aggregation operator `group_concat` which allows you to collapse the grouped results into a single row. In your case it would go something like this:

```
SELECT
  `user`.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`group`.group_name)
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `user_group` ON (`user_group`.user_id = `user`.user_id)
INNER JOIN `group` ON (`group`.group_id = `user_group`.group_id)
GROUP BY `user`.name
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to have `group_id` in your user table if it is many-to-many and you already have a connecting table.

From PHP I guess you use MySQL, so you can use GROUP_CONCAT in situations like this.

Anyway, you are querying a hierarchical structure, which can not gracefully flatted to a single table, so you will always have to do some PHP coding to get the hierchical structure back.

Comment: Thanks, the extra group_id field was a typo on my part.  Removed now.

Answer (score 2):

try with `GROUP_CONCAT` with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT user.name, GROUP_CONCAT(group.name) FROM user
INNER JOIN user_group ON user.id = user_group.user_id 
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user_group.group_id 
GROUP BY user.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match your table structure :)

```
SELECT  `user`.name, GROUP_CONCAT(  `group`.group_name ) 
FROM  `user` 
INNER JOIN  `user_group` ON (  `user_group`.user_id =  `user`.id ) 
INNER JOIN  `group` ON (  `group`.id =  `user_group`.group_id ) 
GROUP BY  `user`.name
```

HTH :)